# Why am I getting these errors, and how can I solve them?

Tags: interpreter, sml

I'm writing an interpreter in Standard ML but I'm having trouble with my the syntax in this function, and I cannot figure out what's wrong.

Here's the relevant code:

```
| eval (rho, SetExp (name, value)) =
    (case rhoContains rho name of
        true    => rhoSet rho name value (rho, value)
    |   false   => globalSet (name, value))


fun rhoSet [] key value = [(key, value)]
  | rhoSet ((elt as (k, v)) :: tail) key value =
        if key = k then (key, value) :: tail else elt :: rhoSet tail key value


fun rhoContains rho name =
    case rhoGet rho name of SOME _ => true | NONE => false
```

This is where SetExp comes from:

```
datatype expression =
    SetExp of (string * expression)
```

Running this gives me a long list of errors but I think this is the relevant section. Line 62 is the line that starts with `true` in `eval`:

```
eval.sml:62: error: Type error in function application.
  Function: rhoSet rho name value : (string * expression) list
  Argument: (rho, value) : (string * expression) list * expression
  Reason: Value being applied does not have a function type
```

Answer (score 2):

You're passing too many arguments to `rhoSet` - remove the trailing pair.

```
| eval (rho, SetExp (name, value)) =
    (case rhoContains rho name of
        true    => rhoSet rho name value
    |   false   => globalSet (name, value))
```

You can also make this more readable with a conditional:

```
| eval (rho, SetExp (name, value)) =
    if rhoContains rho name
    then rhoSet rho name value
    else globalSet (name, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

For SML, in the expression `rhoSet rho name value (rho, value)`, `rhoSet rho name value` is a function and `(rho, value)` is the argument of this function.  However, by the definition of `rhoSet`, `rhoSet rho name value` is necessarily a list and not a function.  That's what the error message means.