# Why am I getting these errors in my sml code?

Tags: sml

I'm creating an interpreter in Standard ML for Standard ML for an assignment but I can't seem to get past this problem.

I have this conditional in a function `eval`:

```
| eval (rho, SetExp (name, value)) =
    (case rhoContains rho name of
        true    => rhoSet rho name value
    |   false   => globalSet (name, value))
```

and these helper functions:

```
fun rhoSet [] key value = [(key, value)]
  | rhoSet ((elt as (k, v)) :: tail) key value =
        if key = k then (key, value) :: tail else elt :: rhoSet tail key value

fun rhoContains rho name =
    case rhoGet rho name of SOME _ => true | NONE => false

fun globalSet key value =
    let fun f [] = [(key, value)]
        | f ((k,v)::tail) = if k = key then (k,value)::tail else (k,v)::f tail
    in globals := f (!globals) end
```

Trying to run this gives me the following errors:

```
eval.sml:61: error: Clauses in case have different types.
Clause 1: true => rhoSet rho name value : bool -> (string * expression) list
Clause 2: false => globalSet (name, value) : bool -> int -> unit
Reason:
    Can't unify (string * expression) list to int -> unit
        (Incompatible types)
```

I'm not sure what's wrong at this point, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this looks similar [Why am I getting these errors, and how can I solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64456373/why-am-i-getting-these-errors-and-how-can-i-solve-them)

Comment: A function must always return values of the same type. How are you planning to use a value that is either a list or `unit`? You're also passing a pair to `globalSet`, which it doesn't expect. (I think you need to spend more time thinking about types and less on writing code.)